# I want to get like ™ character in db. how? in ios

Tags: mysql, ios, database, nsstring

in mysql db table

```
  varchar title(20) - db table column. 
  title: Banana™  - table row.
```

in return.php (server)

```
 $get_query=$_GET['query'];

 $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("die");

mysql_select_db("testdb",$connect);

$query=mysql_query($get_query,$connect);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query ))
{
$list[]=$row;

 }

print json_encode($list);

mysql_free_result($query);

mysql_close($connect);
```

in ios   (client)

```
NSString * szURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/return.php?query=%@",query]; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[szURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]];

NSString *strData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                error:&error];

NSDictionary *rootItem = (NSDictionary *)[strData JSONValue];
NSArray * appLists= (NSArray *)rootItem;

NSMutableArray *resultArray =[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] autorelease];

for(NSDictionary * oneApp in appLists)
{   
   NSString *appTitle=(NSString*)[oneApp objectForKey:@"title"];

 }
```

but appTitle is NULL;

I think , I need to covert character.

™ is problem.
  How I get Banana™ by (NSString *)??

Comment: You should give more details on how you get this string out of the database.

Comment: `opeApp` could be nil, try to `NSLog` it before the `objectForKey` call.

Comment: Would be fun to know how your `PHP` is configured, as well. It might not be handling Unicode strings properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is here:

```
NSDictionary *rootItem = (NSDictionary *)[strData JSONValue];
NSArray * appLists= (NSArray *)rootItem;
```

Is it an Array or a Dictionary? Check this out before iterate over `appLists`. A `NSLog` to `[strData JSONValue];` can be really useful.

Comment: I can just get Banana. but not Banana™.

Comment: Check your PHP configuration, as @Romain said in comments, maybe you are not handling Unicode strings.